# what kind of the error is these [Errno 111] Connection refused and how to solved it?

Tags: django

i try to send mail using django send_mail but when i try send mail from local it can be work properly but production it say error
**"[Errno 111] Connection refused"**

Comment: could you please share your piece of code where you are calling the send_mail function and also your settings.py file where you have specified the email settings (please make sure to remove the actual password of the email)

Answer (score 0):

```
setting.py

 - EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
   EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
   EMAIL_PORT = 587 
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = "dudhpokharicommunityhomestay@gmail.com"
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "............."
```

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
 - def Booking(request):
       if request.method =="POST":
           check_in_date = request.POST['check_in_date']
           check_out_date = request.POST['check_out_date']
           person = request.POST['persons']
           email = request.POST['email']
           phone_number  = request.POST['mobile']
           query_form_data = BookingInquery(check_in_date= check_in_date, 
                                           check_out_date =check_out_date,
                                           person =person,
                                           email_address =email,
                                           phone_number = phone_number
                                           )
           query_form_data.save()
           subject = "Booking Inquery Form"
           message = f"Inquery form detais check in date:"+ check_in_date + 
                    ",check out date:"+ check_out_date +", Email:" +email + ", 
                     phone number:" +phone_number + "total person:"+person 
           email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
           recipient_list = [email_from]
           send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
   
   
           messages.success(request,"booking inquery send successfully..")
           return redirect('app:index')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem is that GMAIL has stopped supporting Less Secure Apps and thus you cannot send mail via GMAIL SMTP as usual. A work around this is (that is if you want to use Gmail SMTP) to have 2FA on your Gmail account and create an "App Password" and use that password in the field:
`EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`

By this, the connection will be accepted and you can send the mail via Gmail SMTP. Right now Gmail's SMTP servers are just rejecting the connection because of them removing support for 'less secure apps'.

You can also just move to another SMTP server, as per your convenience